# Rails 3: Infinity sessions lifetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Now my rails session ends when i close browser. Its' not than i want. I need to create applciations where sessions never ends.

How can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a cookie that will login your user every time (s)he visits your site. If that's what you really want.

Know that when your user closes the browser, the session will not "really" end. Since HTTP is stateless, your server will not know when the browser is closed. Hence, this will not end the session.

So, if you want the session to never end, do as what I said in the first paragraph. But think about the consequences when your users are at a public terminal, like an airport. If somebody logs in your site and closes the browser, and somebody else visits your very site, this person will have previous persons' credentials. Do you really want that?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, there are many gems to handle this. It sounds like you need to read up on sessions first. This is not a Rails-specific or Rails-innovated concept. Basically, you need to create users with passwords that you store in a database in an encrypted manner. As @darioo said, you don't want every user to have the same session, do you?

Once you've read up on the philosophy (google it for a few minutes), then you should look at the following gems:

- Devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
- Warden (used by devise, et. al.): https://github.com/hassox/warden

You can then add devise to your Gemfile and progress from there.